# Place numbers on edges between nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, nodes

I am creating a graph of connected nodes and I want to have numbers on all edges that connect the nodes. At the moment it looks as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=ellipse, draw=black, fill=gray!50] (a) at (7,-4) {a};
\node[shape=ellipse, draw=black, fill=gray!50] (b) at (7,1) {b};
\draw[solid] (b) -- (a) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

If I want the line between a and b have an assigned number, how shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?  The key is use of node

```
\draw[solid] (b) --node[pos=xx,position](){3}(a) ;
```

where xx=0~1 and position= left,right,above,below

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=ellipse, draw=black, fill=gray!50] (a) at (7,-4) {a};
\node[shape=ellipse, draw=black, fill=gray!50] (b) at (7,1) {b};
\draw[solid] (b) --node[midway,right](){1} (a) ;
\draw[solid] (b) --node[pos=0.1,left](){2} (a) ;
\draw[solid] (b) --node[pos=0.9,right](){3}(a) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```